# Get value from pseudo element with python

Tags: python, selenium, pseudo-element

I would like to get the price value from the pseudo element you see on the picture below. If I hover over the mouse only then I can see some value like the price it costs( that is what I need). I found the "move_to_element" so now I can hover over the mouse with the program but I still cant get the price out of the element.
The problem is that even if I hover over my mouse I cant see the element opening in the inspector tab.

Thank you!
[image]

This is the code I would like to get out the :before element from:

```
<div onclick="Game.UpgradesById[503].click(event);" class="crate upgrade enabled" onmouseout="Game.setOnCrate(0);Game.tooltip.shouldHide=1;" onmouseover="if (!Game.mouseDown) {Game.setOnCrate(this);Game.tooltip.dynamic=1;Game.tooltip.draw(this,function(){return function(){return Game.crateTooltip(Game.UpgradesById[503],'store');}();},'store');Game.tooltip.wobble();}" id="upgrade0" style="background-position:-1056px -1296px;"></div>
```

After this there is an en element ::before and end of the div

Comment: Hi @Robin, just providing with the UI image wouldn't help in any way to debug the issue. Please post the code that you tried, and also the website link if possible.

Comment: Sure, this is the link: https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

I can't really provide a code, since I don't have any. I don't have idea how to get an element which is not in the HTML but in the DOM( a pseudo element - :before?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your query on how to extract only the value:

Split the output `x` with the delimiter of next line: `\n` and then get it's first index. That would give you the value. Below are the lines.

```
spl = int(x.split("\n")[0])
print(f'value: {spl}')
print(type(spl))
```

Output:

```
15
???
[owned : 0]
value: 15 # this line is fetched using the above code in this answer. It fetches the value from the `x`
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: I see, thank you, though I divide it and I got my value there, however is still none-type. I try to convert it into a string and after I do it says it is a string, but when I try to iterate or convert it from srting to an int it lets me know it is a none-type EDIT: When I iterate the sting version it itearates - N O N E

Comment: @Robin, I didn't clearly understand what you said. Did my solution work for you?

Comment: Yes your solution works. I could divide the value I would like to have. The original outcome of the x was this:

100
Reinforced index finger
[Upgrade]
The mouse and cursors are twice as efficient.
prod prod
Click to purchase.

With your solution it gives me: 100 which is great.

I would like to use '100' as an integer to be able to work with it as a value. I am trying to convert it somehow to an integer but no luck so far.

Comment: @Robin, updated the code. Now the value would be in `int`. You can perform arithmetic operations on it.
Please accept answer if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I visited the website manually, I get somewhat like what you showed, but when I run through automation, it does not show any Upgrades. Hence, I had to stick to checking the identities (like Grandma, Cursor, etc); but they didn't show in automated version. Only the users `???` are seen. [Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP7tG.jpg)

Eventually, I tried it with `???` only. I tried a different approach, instead of using `::before` or `::after`, I tried to see if any tooltip exists somewhere, and it does exist. The only caveat is that I was able to fetch all the text from the hover (from which again we have to extract what is required through code). On this context, here is the code:

```
driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")
time.sleep(10)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'product0')).perform()
time.sleep(1)
x = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'tooltip').text
print(x)
```

Here is the output:

```
15
???
[owned : 0]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Please change the element to the element that you want and you should get the result.

Comment: Wow Anand, thank you I try it immediately. The reason you could not see the upgrades is probably because at the first time you open it it is not there. Once you bought at least one product( one from the cursor ) then the upgrades will appear( 2 of them ). As the game goes even more.

Comment: I tried it and it works, you are awesome. thank you!

Comment: @RobinGergelyfi Glad to know! Please accept the answer if it works for you. Thanks!

Comment: I accepted. But really was a big help. I found everywhere that you cant get pseudo elements with selenium only with J.S. You should expand to get more people know this. Really awesome.

Comment: An other question, you may know the answer. Do you know how to get out a value of it? For example I would like to get the price of the item which is currently 100( cookies ). With the tooltip I get out everythig which is included in the tooltip. I cant get out only the price because I cant iterate, it is a none type element and I couldn't yet figure it out how to get that value.